# Electron: display encrypted image in application

Tags: node.js, electron

I am making an Electron application that encrypt files. For images files, I want to be able to display them in the app. My code can successfully read and decrypt files but I have no idea how to display them in the application.

For example, how can I assign this data to an image element?

```
const encryption = require('mycustomencryption');

function readEncrypted(filename) {
    var data = ds.readFileSync(filename);
    var decrypted = encryption.decrypt(data);
    return decrypted;
}
```

How would I do something like this? Because the goal is to encrypt images I cannot save a `temp` file on the local disk.

```
$('img').setImageToDecryptedImage(readEncrypted(filename));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

essentially, electron is a web-based tech, in HTML, an IMG tag could has **src** attribute in data format:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,...."/>
```

and your encrypted data only stored in memory.

Comment: Can you explain further?

Comment: essentially, electron is a web-based tech, in HTML, an IMG tag could has src attribute in data format, eg: <img src="data:image/png;base64,...."/>, your encrypted data only stored in memory.